# Manage product zoom functionality in Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, jquery

I want to convert Magento magnifier cursor as mouse cursor. Currently Magento roomer has big size.

I want to use some thing like in mentioned URL "http://www.fitatti.com/cami.html".

Please help.

Comment: Image section keeps on loading on the given URL. Can you review it once more.

Comment: Arushi check your browser or open in private browser . it's working good, it's mean its not loading